# Importing cython Extension Class into python file (positional argument

Tags: python, cython

I have two files: a run.py and a constraints.pyx. I want to create an extension class similar to L1Penalty in [this code](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/lightning/blob/master/lightning/impl/sag_fast.pyx), in constraints.pyx, and instantiate it in run.py to be used in a function.

What I've done :

constraints.pyx contains an extension class, a subclass of the Penalty class in [this code](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/lightning/blob/master/lightning/impl/sag_fast.pxd) :

```
from lightning.impl.sag_fast cimport Penalty

cdef class ProbaPenalty(Penalty):
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.support_lagged = False
...
```

In run.py I create an instance of ProbaPenalty:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
from constraints import ProbaPenalty
pen = ProbaPenalty()
```

The error that I have is :

> **cinit**() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)

Is there a careless mistake? I can't find a similar problem on stackoverflow. 
I tried changing my cinit to take in a bint support_lagged such that I now have

```
cdef class ProbaPenalty(Penalty):
    def __cinit__(self, bint support_lagged):
        self.support_lagged = support_lagged
```

And then using

```
pen = ProbaPenalty(0)
```

This time, I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'custom_constraints.ProbaPenalty' object has no attribute 'b'

Where did I call b, and where does b even come from?

At the start, I wanted ProbaPenalty to have a vector of doubles b, and I did cinit(self, double* b), but I have since changed the code, deleted the .c and .so files, etc., looking into the current .c file, there is no attribute b either.

I have also tried compiling with a setup.py, with the same problem.

Comment: Based on OPs comment under the answer I'm voting to close as "can no longer be reproduced"

Answer (score 0):

The `__cinit__` method is not suitable for Python-level access to the extension types, see http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference/extension_types.html

Define a reguar `__init__` for use from Python.

Comment: I actually tried running what I had again this morning, after closing and reopening spyder - it works even with __cinit__. 

In any case, it wouldn't have explained why there was an attribute b. I guess there were somehow variables saved that weren't cleared when I re-ran my setup.py.